# JUnit theories sets params to null

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a test class that using theories like this:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class XTest(){
    public static X x1;
    public static X x2;
    @DataPoints("xlist")
    public static X[] xList = {x1, x2};
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
        x1 = new X();
        x2 = new X();
}

@Theory
public void test(@FromDataPoints("xlist" x){
 // x is null
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting `x` as null. I tried the same with parameterized tests and still null. What am I missing here?

Comment: _xList_ is created before `setUp()`  gets executed, so xList is defined as `X[] xList = {null, null};`. You could annotate the setup with [BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) or initialise _x1_ and _x2_ in a static scope.

Comment: @matansab did you try the solution i give you??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem within your code is coming from the "init" order.

xList is **static**; therefore that initializer code is executed when your test class is **loaded** the first time. At this point in time, the two fields x1 and x2 are still at **null** - as the @Before method will run **later** on.

So, a simply fix here could be to not use @Before at all, but go for:

```
public static X x1 = new X();
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the structure of your class to make it work as I know about Theory, this would be the right structure:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class TheoryTest {

    @DataPoints("xlist")
    public static Integer[] xList = new Integer[] {new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(45)};


    @Theory
    public void singleTest(@FromDataPoints("xlist") Integer x){
        // x is null
        System.out.println("Size " +x);
    }
}
```

What is going to do is call your method "singleTest" one time for each of the values in the array "xlist", so will be called 3 times with values

```
xList = 1
xList = 2
xList = 45
```

You dont need to declare single variables x1,x2.